# how to get request body text using bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

I'm using bottle to receive POST webhook from bitbucket. The body of the POST contains info about what changed in the repo, etc. I am able to do this fine with `@post('/myroute')`, however I'm having trouble getting to the actual POST body data text.

here is an image that shows what I'm doing end to end
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAt1p.png

When printed to console`request.body` yields:

> StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x7fa13341c4d0

and `request.body.dir()` yields:

> AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'dir'

I'm wondering how do I get to the actual text of the request body (or inspect the object somehow to find the same)?

the POST request body will look something like this:

http://pastebin.com/SWjLrHig

I've also tried `request.json` (no luck)

any advice?

EDIT:
i ended up using this:

```
from bottle import get, post, request, run
import urllib
import json

@post('/bitbucket')
def postToJSON():
    body = request.body.read()
    body = body.replace("+","").replace("payload=","")
    parsedBody = urllib.unquote(body).decode('utf8')
    print parsedBody
    jsonObj = json.loads(parsedBody)
    print jsonObj
```

interesting now, parsedBody looks good:

```
{"repository":{"website":null,"fork":false,"name":"test","scm":"git","owner":"
testName","absolute_url":"/testNameTest/test/","slug":"test","is_private":true},"trunc
ated":false,"commits":[{"node":"04554d6980dd","files":[{"type":"modified","file"
:"stacker.py"}],"raw_author":"TestName<testName@testName.info>","utctimestamp":"
2015-05-2815:30:03+00:00","author":"testName","timestamp":"2015-05-2817:30:03","
raw_node":"04554d6980dd3c5fe4c3712d95b49fcf9b8da4f4","parents":["7f98b4e7532e"],
"branch":"master","message":"foo\n","revision":null,"size":-1}],"canon_url":"htt
ps://bitbucket.org","user":"testName"}
```

but jsonObj is not so good:

```
{u'commits': [{u'node': u'7f98b4e7532e', u'files': [{u'type': u'modified', u'fil
e': u'stacker.py'}], u'branch': u'master', u'utctimestamp': u'2015-05-2815:24:50
+00:00', u'author': u'TestName', u'timestamp': u'2015-05-2817:24:50', u'raw_node
': u'7f98b4e7532e02d53d83a29ec2073c5a5eac58c8', u'parents': [u'019e77d2e0d3'], u
'raw_author': u'TestNamer<TestName@TestName.info>', u'message': u'foo\n', u'size'
: -1, u'revision': None}], u'user': u'TestName', u'canon_url': u'https://bitbuck
et.org', u'repository': {u'website': None, u'fork': False, u'name': u'test', u's
cm': u'git', u'absolute_url': u'/ericTest/test/', u'owner': u'TestName', u'slug'
: u'test', u'is_private': True}, u'truncated': False}
```

however, when I do something like

```
print jsonObj['repository']['name']
```

it works as expected (just prints the name 'test')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the bottle documentation states, the request data is "a file like object". http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#the-raw-request-body

So you access the raw body using `read()`.

Also, `dir` is not a *method* of objects, it's a freestanding function which you call *passing* an object.

```
dir(request.body)
```

And googling for `StringIO` should have brought you here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html

Comment: i did arrive at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html before posting, but the usage was not obvious to me, and I do not see read() on that page (athough it seems to work).  The string returned by read()  however returns a very ugly encoding, all " and { are replaced with %22%2C+%22.  Is there an elegant way to ingest this as json, or perhaps a stringio > json method?  I'm trying to avoid parsing it with text manipulation....

Comment: @3z33etm The StringIO documentation suggests reading the file-object-documentation. But yes, an example for reading would be nice. File an issue ;) Regarding the encoding issues: it's probably some form of urlencoding, which can be decoded using urllib or cgi modules. Take a look at the headers of the request. That might be the reason why the `request.json` doesn't work.